# Вопрос о правильности падежа

Tags: падежи

Правильный ли падеж слова "Конституция" во фразе в бюллетене для голосования - "Одобряете ли вы поправки в КонституциЮ РФ?" То есть правильно ли окончание *-ю* для слова Конституция?

Answer (score 3):

Да, правильный. Речь идёт о том, **куда** *вносятся* поправки (их пока нет в Конституции), — поправки (*вносимые или предлагаемые к внесению*) в Конституци**ю**. Другой падеж (**где?**) возможен в контексте уже внесённых поправок:

> Одобряете ли вы поправки (*сделанные*) в Конституци**и** РФ?

**P.S.** C опубликованным на 20-е число ЦИК проектом бюллетеня (https://s0.rbk.ru/v6_top_pics/resized/1180xH/media/img/1/81/755847097377811.jpeg) вопрос отдельный: там фигурируют не "поправки...", а "Вы одобряете *изменения в Конституцию*?" Такая замена обычного существительного ("поправка" здесь не является трактовкой действия "исправления") отглагольным (от сильно выраженного *переходного* глагола) *нарушает* падежную сочетаемость (правильно: "*/предложенные/ изменения /в/ Конституци**и***"). Реальная юридическая формулировка того, что выносится на голосование, вообще *другая* (она для понимания голосующих упрощена): "Закон о поправк**е** к Конституции" - дело в том, что *один* закон может относиться к единственной "поправке".

Comment: Меня напрягает причастие в скобках и запятая, нужная только в том случае, если скобки убрать...

Comment: Уберу запятую (даже не уверен, что сам ставил).

Answer (score 3):

Одобряете ли вы поправки (к чему?) к Конституции РФ.

Вносить поправки (во что) в Конституцию РФ.

Изменения (в чем) в Конституции РФ.

Грамота:

Добрый день! Скажите, пожалуйста, как все-таки правильно: "поправка к Конституции" или "в Конституцию"? Всегда считала, что поправка принимается к документу, а не в документ. Но последние годы постоянно слышу по радио и читаю в газетах о поправках "в Конституцию".

Спасибо!

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Правильно: поправка к Конституции (предложить поправки к Конституции, рассмотреть поправки к Конституции, принять поправки к Конституции). Но: внести поправки в Конституцию.

Как правильно написать: Изменения внесены в декларацию или Изменения внесены в декларации

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Используйте первый вариант.